# Template hierarchy at Twig and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

I'm building a `/app/Resources/base.html.twig` with common features for almost all the development I have since for example all use Twitter Bootstrap, Select2 and some common libraries. Then for any project I created a bundle called `TemplateBundle` and inside it I have a template called `layout.html.twig` which extends from `base.html.twig`. Having this as a start point I have some doubts around my approach:

- In `base.html.twig` I handle assets with Assetic and I have this lines:

  ```
  {% block stylesheets %}
      {% stylesheets 
              'bundles/template/css/bootstrap.min.css' 
              'bundles/template/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' 
              'bundles/template/css/font-awesome.min.css' 
              'bundles/template/css/select2.css' 
              'bundles/template/css/select2-bootstrap.css' 
              'bundles/template/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css' 
              'bundles/template/css/datepicker.css' 
              'bundles/template/css/datepicker3.css' 
              'bundles/template/css/styles.css' 
         filter='cssrewrite' 
      %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
      {% endstylesheets %}
  {% endblock %}
  ```

I want to make `base.html.twig` as extendable as can be and in the code above not all of my sites uses `datepicker.css` or `styles.css` since this are part of the current one or in other cases files names changed between sites, so my question regarding this is: how I handle this in `layout.html.twig`? For example in Site1 all the templates will extends from `layout.html.twig` and then in this layout I can set the use of `datepicker` and `styles` but for Site2 I could define to use just `styles` and so on, so how to handle this in `layout.html.twig` maintaining assetic?

- As you may notice all my assets resides on `TemplateBundle` but what happens if tomorrow I called this Template1Bundle? Then I should take care of `base.html.twig` and change any assetic path, how do you handle this? I mean where do you put your common files as this one for example?

Understand my question?

Comment: Why handle it? Why not just create a specific layout template for each website? This looks like more hassle then it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base template will be very complicated. I will rather to have multi layout instead. Since you have everything in a bundle.

Another option is use have the common ones in base.html.twig. and extends at layout.html.twig with `{{ parent() }}` which will print the base.html.twig block content, 
but you will lose the front end performance in production.

`base.html.twig`

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/template/css/bootstrap.min.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

`layout.html.twig`

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% stylesheets 
        'bundles/template/css/datepicker.css' 
        'bundles/template/css/datepicker3.css'
    filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What you mean with "lose the front end performance in production"?

Comment: By combining the stylesheets in a single output file will reduce the number of requests, which only happen when its at production after the `assetic:dump` command. From many files into one single file.